# Highstock/highcharts show multiple y-axis values in single tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highstock chart with two y-axes.  When I mouseover the chart, the default tooltip only shows one of the y-axis, unless I directly put my mouse over the excluded series' point.  Is there a way to just show both y-axes in the tooltip at whatever x value the mouse is over in the chart?

Answer (score 1):

Set `tooltip.shared = true`

See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared and http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true-mixed-types/

Comment: Yeah tried that, but I can only see both items in the tooltip if I have my mouse over the non-primary y-axis.  If I move my mouse somewhere else in the chart area only one series is in the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need something which map points between axis. Its not built-in, but you can use formatter and prepare something like this:

```
formatter: function(){
            var y = this.y,
                txt = 'y1: ' + y,
                yAxis = this.series.yAxis,
                index = this.series.yAxis.options.index == 0 ? 1 : 0,
                oAxis = this.series.chart.yAxis[index];

            txt += '<br>y2: ' + oAxis.toValue(yAxis.toPixels(y));

            return txt;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bu7ryzfL/